# How to delete system partitions from old OS drive, and extend main partition?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd

I had a 1 TB drive with the OS installed and everything (disk 2 in the screenshot), and recently upgraded to a new SSD that has a brand new installation of Windows 10 (disk 1 in the screenshot).

[image]

I would like now to recover the system partitions from the old drive (boot and recovery) and get the additional 550 MB to the (almost) 1 TB main partition.

So far I only succeeded in removing the boot partition (hence the unallocated 101 MB). I do not have the option to remove the recovery partition. When I try to extend 931 GB partition, it says I need to convert it to a dynamic drive and then cries about no available place.

So two questions:

1. How do I delete the recovery partition from disk 2, which is no longer the system drive where the OS is installed?
2. How do I extend the 930 GB partition to use the entire unallocated space?

There are some related questions on the website, but none answer my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually i recommend [Minitool Partition Wizard (free tool)](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) or [AOMEI Partition (free tool)](https://www.disk-partition.com/download-home.html) for that. It does excellent job!